# Symfony Mongo query: select max

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, mongodb-query, query-builder

I am trying to understand how aggregation works in mongo queries. For example, I have document `Product` with `category` field. How can I select latest added product from each category?

```
class Product {
     /**
      * @MongoDB\Id
      */
     protected $id;

     /**
      * @MongoDB\Field(type="integer")
      */
     protected $category;
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
class ProductRepository extends DocumentRepository
{

    public function lastProducts()
    {
         $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
         $qb->max('id');
         $qb->group(['category'], []);

         return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    }
}
```

When I run this query I get `Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\MongoDB\Exception\ResultException: "not code"`

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the last product, sort them by id desc, then limit your query to 1 element:

```
public function lastProducts()
{
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();

     $qb->sort('p.id', 'desc')
        ->from('UserBundle\Product', 'p')
        ->limit(1)
     ;

     return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: this entity query builder! this won't work with mongo documents

Comment: For any future people that find this question, user4666065 is entirely correct that this is the ORM not the ODM. The correct answer can be found at: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/21660153/3579432](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21660153/3579432)